# import Json formatted values to create bar charts with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I want to visualize data from my home automation middle ware (ioBroker) .
The data can be loaded as a json string via a URL.

When I copy the data directly into the script it works, but I want to load the data dynamically.
The loading itself works (get the json string in console) but how do I get the content of the variable "out" into the myChartConfig declaration??
Have tried many things but didn't work.

the Json - text provided by the url:

```
{labels : ['2017-10','2017-9','2017-8','2017-7','2017-6','2017-5','2017-4','2017-3','2017-2','2017-1','2016-12','2016-11'], datasets : [{label: 'PV Eigenverbr.', data: [235,341,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], backgroundColor:['LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ']},{label: 'PV Produktion', data: [473,775,96,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], backgroundColor:['LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue']},{label: 'PV Einspeisung', data: [238,433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], backgroundColor:['LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen']},{label: 'Bezug aus Netz', data: [572,575,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], backgroundColor:['red','red','red','red','red','red','red','red','red','red','red','red']}]}
```

The script:

```
<script>

   url='http://192.168.0.201:8087/getPlainValue/javascript.1.Statistiken.12_Monate.stromAuswertungGesamt';
    var out;
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
        console.log('Checkout this JSON! ', out);
        // output of console is exactly the json string
    })
    .catch(err => { throw err });

    var myContext = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChartConfig = {
      type: 'bar',
      /this is schould be replaced by "out" 
      data: {labels : ['2017-10','2017-9','2017-8','2017-7','2017-6','2017-5','2017-4','2017-3','2017-2','2017-1','2016-12','2016-11'], datasets : [{label: 'PV Eigenverbr.', data: [235,341,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], backgroundColor:['LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ','LightSeaGreen ']},{label: 'PV Produktion', data: [473,775,96,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], backgroundColor:['LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue','LightSkyBlue']},{label: 'PV Einspeisung', data: [238,433,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], backgroundColor:['LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen','LightGreen']},{label: 'Bezug aus Netz', data: [572,575,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], backgroundColor:['red','red','red','red','red','red','red','red','red','red','red','red']}]}
    }
  var myChart = new Chart(myContext, myChartConfig);
</script>
```

any hints ??

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way.
fetch(url) returns a promise, meaning the function doesn't necessarily finish before you use the return value.
You have to put the rest of your code inside the second then.
You can easily see that if you use console.log(out) under the then-catch chain, it will print the value before the console.log('Checkout this JSON! ', out), and it will log out `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, let's try this:
I replaced the fetch promise and the json promise with other promises, just for you to see the syntax. Let's say the payload is what is returned from the fetch -

```
const payload = {value: "someValue"};

Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve(payload)
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then((out) => {
    var myContext = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChartConfig = {
  type: 'bar',
  //this is schould be replaced by "out" 
  data: payload
}
var myChart = new Chart(myContext, myChartConfig);
})
.catch(err => { throw err });
```

As you can see, I relocated the rest of the function into the second `then`, where `out` has the value of the resolved promise.

You can see the working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/14ahott9/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmm that is pretty much the same I tried yesterday - but there is no bar chart - and no error in console.

Comment: Hello,
first of all, thank you for your support. That's what I tried yesterday.
If I understood you correctly, it would have to work if I replace "someValue" with  my Json string in your example - right ?
Unfortunately, no graphics will be shown - but also no error in the console.
I have hardly any idea of javascript and seem to be a bit overwhelmed here.

Comment: If there's no error, that's a good thing.
If no data is being shown, maybe it isn't correctly formatted. First try finding the right type of data that the Chart constructor is expecting, and then give it actual data.